# difference between "looking" and "looked" here-

Tags: past-participles, grammaticality-in-context, present-participles, participle-clauses

> 1. It left the German Embassy ***looking*** as though it had been
>      racked by an earthquake.
> 2. It left the German Embassy ***looked*** as though it had been racked
>      by an earthquake.

Is the #2 a correct sentence? What is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The news left me stunned.
>
> The drink left me feeling queasy.
>
> The boiler explosion left the building in ruins.
>
> The boiler explosion left the building looking as though it had been
>   hit by an earthquake.

**to leave [something/someone] {complement}** can be understood to mean "to put [something/someone] into the *state* expressed by {complement}.

*States* are expressed by adjectives, prepositional phrases, and *non-finite* forms of verbs used adjectivally as object complements (phrases introduced by the present participle, or the past participle as adjective).

To express a resultant state, we cannot use a finite (tensed) verb like **looked**:

> It left the embassy looked... <sup>ungrammatical</sup>

and the past participle of **look**, **looked**, does not express a resultant state and thus cannot be used as an adjectival object complement.  If we look at something, it does not become **looked** (but *looked at*).  **Look** is unlike **see** in that regard.  When we *see* something, it does become **seen**.

In the explosion example, **look** means "to seem, to appear".  The past participle of that verb does not express a resultant state either.

P.S. To hone this a bit, it not just a *resulant state* but a state that is the direct result of subject's action. The verb whose past participle form is used as the object complement must express an action that the *subject* does. For that reason, we cannot say:

> The storm left many trees *fallen*.  <sup>ungrammatical</sup>

Answer (score 0):

#2 is incorrect. Not many native speakers will be able to give you a good answer as to why and you will receive different answers from different people. You could say:

> The German Embassy looked as though it had been racked by an earthquake.

This means that it looked that way in the past and does not look that way now. In 1, at the time that the person leaves, the German Embassy looks as such which is why *looking* is used.

Also, *racked* is quite a rare word and you're not likely to encounter it again soon.

Answer (score 0):

Your first sentence is correct using a *participle phrase*

> It left the German Embassy **looking** as though it had been racked by an earthquake.
>   *(The storm)* left the German Embassy **looking** as though it had been racked by an earthquake.

meaning the state of the embassy was in *tatters*.

Your second sentence could be rephrased as

> The German Embassy **looked** as though it had been racked by an earthquake.

where the "*final*" state of the embassy is implied.

The meaning of both is the same, that "*the embassy received a high degree of damage.*".

Comment: Peter, that's my downvote.   What is the subject of **looked** in the second sentence?

Comment: Whatever "it" refers to is the subject.  That should be obvious "It left the German Embassy" + "It looked as though it had been racked by an earthquake" = "It left the German Embassy **and** *(it)* looked as though it had been racked by an earthquake."

Comment: Although it's grammatically possible to construe the sentence so that "left" means "exited", semantically it's somewhat far-fetched. But I can't remove my downvote unless you make an edit of some kind.

Comment: Interesting, it never occurred to me to read the sentence as you are suggesting, I thought along the lines of "*The car* left the German Embassy looking as though it had been racked by an earthquake."

Answer (score 0):

> It left the German Embassy ***looking*** as though it had been racked by an earthquake.

The verb - *leave* - can license carious complements. Among them, this is quite a common and natural pattern -

- Complement (*Subject*) + LEAVE + Complement (*Object*) + Objective Predicative Complement.

Example -

> [He] LEFT [the knife] [sticking to the butter].

The elements in brackets corresponds to the functions referred above in the same order. Here the Objective Predicative Complement is realised by the Gerund-Participle clause - *sticking to the butter*. The subject of the clause is implied; it's the Object of the sentence - *the knife*.

> [He] LEFT [the child] [seated in his favourite chair].

Here in this sentence the Objective Predicative Complement is realised by a Past-Participle clause - *seated in his favourite chair*.

So the verb - *leave* - can license both a Gerund-Participle Clause and a Past-Participle Clause as its Objective Predicative Complement. Favouring one over the other depends on situations. In your sentence -

> It left the German Embassy ***looking*** as though it had been racked by an earthquake.

The only correct option is *looking*. We can't use *looked*.

Past-Participle clause is only possible if we could write - *something or somebody looked the German embassy as though it had been racked by as earthquake*.